# Building a linked list as the basis of a graph Null pointer errors

Tags: java, graph, nullpointerexception, linked-list

I am trying to build a graph based on a linked list, where I build the linked list of nodes, and each node points to a linked list of edges. I build the graph based on an input file.

My input file will be on the following scheme:

> Number of Nodes in graph
>
> SourceNode1 EndNode1
>
> SourceNode2 EndNode2
>
> ....

For example:

```
4 //Number of nodes

1 2 //An edge between 1 and 2

1 3 //An edge between 1 and 3

2 4 //An edge between 2 and 4
```

An assumption is that the nodes in the graph will numbered 1 through the number of nodes and that no node will have more than 1 "parent" (though a node might have more than 1 "child").

My problem is trying to build the linked list containing the nodes. Each node has 3 fields: the edges coming from that node, the node value (1, 2, 3, etc.), and the next node (because is a linked list of nodes). I attempt to parse in the number of nodes, create a first node manually, and attach the rest of the nodes in an in an iterative fashion.

Note: The parent field is for some external analysis unrelated to this question. You can ignore it.

Node class:

```
public class Node {
  private Edge firstEdge;
  private Node parent;
  private Node nextNode;
  private int element;

  //Constructor
  public Node() {
    parent = null;
    firstEdge = null;
    nextNode = null;
  }

  //Accsessor and Modifier Methods
  public void setElement(int e) {element = e;}
  public Node getNextNode() {return nextNode;}  
  public Edge getFirstEdge() {return firstEdge;}
  public void setFirstEdge(Edge a) {firstEdge = a;}
  public void setNextNode(Node a) {nextNode = a;}
  public int getElement() {return element;}
  public Node getParent() {return parent;}
  public void setParent(Node p) {parent = p;}

  //Checks for a non-null parent
  public boolean hasParent() { return parent == null; }

  //checks iff node has next edge
  public boolean hasFirstEdge() { return firstEdge == null; }

  //checks if a node has a next node
  public boolean hasNextNode() { return nextNode == null; }

}
```

Edge class:

```
public class Edge {
 //Instance Variables
 private Node nextNode;
 private Edge nextEdge;

 //Constructor
 public Edge() {
  nextNode = null;
  nextEdge = null;
 }

 //Accsessor and Modifier Methods
 public void setNextNode(Node a) {nextNode = a;}
 public void setNextEdge(Edge a) {nextEdge = a;}
 public Node getNextNode() {return nextNode;}
 public Edge getNextEdge() {return nextEdge;}

 public boolean hasNextEdge() {
  return nextEdge == null;
 }
}
```

Driver class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Driver {
  public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException{
    //Get text file for building the graph
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter the text file name: ");
    String fileName = console.nextLine();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    //in contains the file reading scanner


    int numNodes = in.nextInt(); //first line of the text file

    Node first = new Node(); //first is head of the list
    first.setElement(1);

    int i = 2; //counter

    //Build the nodes list; I get problems in this loop
    while (i <= numNodes) {
      Node head = new Node(); //Tracker node
      head = first; //head is the first node of the list

      /*Loop to end of the list*/          
      while(head.hasNextNode()) {

        //Null check; without it, I get NullPointerExceptions.
        //If it is not needed, or there is a better way, please inform me.
        if (head.getNextNode() == null) {
          break;
        }

        head = head.getNextNode(); //get to the end of the ilst    
      }


      //Next node to add
      Node newNode = new Node();
      newNode.setElement(i); //Because of the 1, 2, 3 nature of the graph 

      head.setNextNode(newNode); //Set the last element as the next node

      i++;
    }

    //Manually check if graph is made (check if the nodes are linked correctly)
    System.out.println("First elem (expect 1): " + first.getElement());
    System.out.println("Second elem (expect 2): " + first.getNextNode().getElement()); //It prints 4 here for some reason

    System.out.println("Third elem (expect 3): " + first.getNextNode().getNextNode().getElement()); //Getting a NullPointerException

    System.out.println("Fourth elem (expect 4): " + first.getNextNode().getNextNode().getNextNode().getElement());

    System.out.println("Expecting null: " + first.getNextNode().getNextNode().getNextNode().getNextNode().getElement());
}
```

When I'm checking if the graph is built, I get problems. I am manually checking it (for this small graph, its possible), and simply print out the first node and the value of the subsequent nodes. I am expecting 1, 2, 3, 4, and null (for the element past 4, because it does not exist). The first node is fine, it prints 1. Calling first.getNextNode().getElement() prints 4, for some odd reason. And calling the node after that gives a NullPointerException. Could someone help me solve this problem?

Note: I haven't added the edges yet. I am just trying to get the core of the linked list of nodes built.

This is my first post on stack overflow. I apologize if it is vague, ambigous, overly detailed, lacking in information, or is a duplicate question. I could not find the answer anywhere else. All input is welcome and appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like something that the debugger would be an ideal tool to help solve...

Comment: I'm not too sold on your design. Given a Node, how am I supposed to get a list of all Edges connected to it? Once I hop to `firstEdge`, there's no way to get any more. I think your node struct should have an array of pointers to edges, and your edge struct should contain two node pointers. That's all you should need to construct a graph.

Comment: @Red: firstEdge is a linked list (it may have been better to name it as edgeList). Once you call firstEdge, use a loop and have a temporary edge point to firstEdge. Then loop until the end of the list using temp = temp.getNextEdge(). However, my problem is not related to the edge building, but rather the node linking.

Comment: The issue is you can't represent the edges as a linked list. Linked lists are 1 dimensional data structures, but a graph is 2 dimensional. How can I loop over edge->nextEdge to get all node edges, when an edge isn't exclusive to a node? Say for instance I start at node A, and use your method to get all edges connected to node A. I use one to go to node B, and use the same method to get all of its edges - remember, one of those edges is shared with node A. Will nextEdge give me another edge connected to A, or to B?

Comment: I suppose you could get around that adding redundant/directional entries for edges, but I don't see why you'd want the added complexity.

Comment: firstEdge is the first outgoing edge from the given node. So for node B, it will return all of the outgoing nodes from B, and the same applies for A. So firstEdge is exclusive to a given node and represents only the outgoing edges from that node. I should have mentioned that this is a directed graph.

Comment: The firstEdge field is used later on in the program (not shown in the question) to retrieve and compute information regarding the graph.

Comment: alright, that makes sense. That aside, I don't see why `nextNode`  needs to be part of your node class. Since you are already storing all outgoing edges from a node, what additional info does a list of the nodes they are connected to give? You are opening yourself up to a lot of potential bugs by effectively linking your nodes together twice.

Comment: The use of nextNode is to be able to quickly go down the linked list of nodes without having to enter the liked list of edges multiple times, for example given nodes 1 linked to 2 linked to 3, it is simple to reach 3 from 1 by using nextNode (for 1 nextNode hold 2, for 2 nextNode holds 3 and so on). If the nextNode field did not exist then you would have to check all of the outgoing edges from 1, then 2 till you find 3, making it a far less efficient process and much longer in terms of code.

Comment: In your example, the "most efficient" way to get to node3 would be to assign it to a variable and access that way.

If you want to work with an abitrary graph, then using that pointer to traverse is useless, since it ignores `e-1` nodes every step, given the node has `e` outgoing edges

Answer (score 0):

Much of your naming is very confusing and is in serious need of clarifying refactorization. `Edge`'s `nextNode` should be called `destinationNode` or something along those lines to make it clear you are dereferencing from an `Edge` object instead of from another `Node`.

Now, let's delve into the actual implementation.

```
Node head = new Node(); //Tracker node
head = first; //head is the first node of the list
```

What's going on here? It looks like you set your local variable `head` to be a brand new `Node`; that's great. Except the very next line, you discard it and set it to the value of your `first` variable.

Then you traverse all the way to the end of the list with a `while` loop, then create *another* new `Node` (this one you actually use). (Normally if you wanted to add something to the end of the list you should be utilizing a doubly linked list, or should at least have pointers to both the first *and* the last elements... i.e., `first` always stays the same, but when you add a new node you simply say `newNode = new Node(); last.nextNode = newNode; last = newNode;` and then configure the new element from there. The way you are doing it, it's taking O(N^2) time to construct a singly-linked list with N elements, hardly ideal.

I also have some preferential criticism about the construction of your minor classes... if you are allowing values to be freely get and set to any value with public setters and getters without taking any action whatsoever when they change, you get the exact same functionality from simply marking those fields public and doing away with the getters and setters entirely. If you have any plans to add more functionality in the future it's fine the way it is, but if they are just going to be dumb linked list elements whose actual uses are implemented elsewhere then you are better off treating the class more like a struct.

Here's a good way to build a singly-linked `Node` list the way you're looking to:

```
int numNodes = in.nextInt(); //first line of the text file

// sentinel value indicating the beginning of the list
Node header = new Node();
header.setElement(-1);

// last node in the list
Node last = first;

// this loop constructs a singly linked ring from the header
for (int i = 1; i <= numNodes; i++) {
  Node newNode = new Node();
  newNode.setElement(i);
  newNode.setNextNode(header);
  last.setNextNode(newNode);
  last = newNode;
}

// do your debug outputs here
// for instance, this loop always outputs every node in the list:
for (Node n = header.getNextNode(); n != header; n = n.getNextNode()) {
  System.out.println("Node " + n.getElement());
}
```

Note that the use of `header` as a [sentinel value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) guarantees that for any `Node` that's already been built, `getNextNode()` will never return `null`.

Again, all this code can be made much more readable by making the fields in your `Node` and `Edge` classes public and scrapping the getters and setters. `header.getNextNode().getNextNode().getNextNode()` can become `header.nextNode.nextNode.element` and so forth.

---

**Stage 2**

Now that that's out of the way, we have the question of how useful this type of structure will actually be for your application. My biggest concern in looking at this is the fact that, when applying edges between nodes on your graph, you will need to access arbitrarily indexed `Node`s to attach edges to them... and while every `Node` already knows what its element index is, getting the Nth node takes N steps because your entire set of nodes is in a linked list.

Remember, the main advantage of using a linked list is the ability to *remove* arbitrary elements in O(1) time as you step through the list. If you are only building a list and aren't going to ever remove anything from it, arrays are often faster -- *especially* if you *ever* need to access arbitrary elements.

What if you don't need to guarantee they're in any particular order or access them by their index, but you need to be able to **add, access-by-ID, and remove** them very quickly for larger data sets? `HashSet` may be the thing for you! What if you still need to be able to access them all in the order they were added? `LinkedHashSet` is your best friend. With this, you could easily even give the nodes names that are strings with no real slowdown.

As for the edges, I feel you are already doing fine: it's probably best to implement the outgoing edges for each `Node` in a singly linked list, assuming you will rarely be removing edges or will have a small number of edges per node and will always access them all together. To add a new edge, simply say `newEdge = new Edge(); newEdge.nextEdge = firstEdge; firstEdge = newEdge;` and you're done, having added the new edge to the beginning of the list. (Singly linked lists are easiest to use as stacks rather than queues.)

For extra fancy-points, implement `Iterable<Edge>` with your `Node` class and make a little `Iterator` class so you can use [extended-for](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) to visit every edge and make your life even easier!

Comment: So, why are you setting last = first? The goal is not a circular linked list, but rather a straight linked list. The program illustrated above (in the question) is going to be used to check for cycles in the graph, so if it is a circular liked list it will always return true for a cycle.

Comment: when you create the first node, it IS the last node. The pointer to the last node continually updates as you add nodes. That being said, having a last node at all in this context is ambiguous to begin with.

Comment: I agree with @Red, there should be no lastNode as this is a linear linked list.

Comment: While I agree that there are more efficient ways to created the graph and check for cycles, I prefer to use a linked list, the portion of code that I have already built that checks for cycles takes advantage of the liked list functionality.

Comment: [Here, I wrote this for you.](http://pastebin.com/dH2uUD5D) That's probably how I'd do it. Bear in mind I didn't check over this super carefully as I gotta fly. Also, a circular linked list doesn't mean the graph will have circular references. The two are totally unrelated. The pastebin above doesn't use a circular linked list because it's not really necessary at all.

Answer (score 0):

As @Widdershins says, the terms used makes the algorithm hard to understand.

I would recommend two things in order to refactor your code:

1. Review the terminology (maybe this helps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory). I know that it sounds like a silly recommendation, but using proper terms will help you a lot to review the object model.
2. Use a better representation. In your code a `Node` fills multiple roles, which makes the code hard to follow.

A good representation will depend a lot of the kind of problems that you try to resolve. For example an [Adjacency List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list), or a [Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) are useful to apply some algorithms of graph theory.

But if you only want to exercise with an object oriented design, is useful to start with the basics.

Take the definition of a Graph in mathematics: `G = (V, E)`... a graph is a pair of a set of nodes and a set of edges between those nodes, and translate it to code:

(the example uses fields for brevity)

```
class DirectedGraph {
    final Set<Node> nodes = new HashSet<Node>();
    final Set<Edge> edges = new HashSet<Edge>();
}
```

Now you need to extend this definition. You can do it step by step. I did the same to end with this representation:

```
class DirectedGraph {
    final Set<Node> nodes = new HashSet<Node>();
    final Set<Edge> edges = new HashSet<Edge>();

    public Node addNode(Object value) { 
        Node newNode = new Node(value);
        nodes.add(newNode); 
        return newNode; 
    }

    public Edge addEdge(Node src, Node dst) {
        Edge newEdge = new Edge(src, dst);
        edges.add(newEdge); 
        return newEdge; 
    }

    private assertValidNode(Node n) {
        if (n.graph != this)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Node " + n + " not part of the graph");
    }

    public Set<Node> successorsOf(Node n) {
        assertValidNode(n);
        Set<Node> result = new HashSet<Node>();
        for (Edge e : edges) {
            if (e.src == n) { result.add(e.dst); }
        }
        return result;
    }

    class Node { 
        final graph = DirectedGraph.this;
        final Object value;
        Node(Object v) {
            this.value = v;
        }
        public String toString() { return value.toString(); }

        public Set<Node> successors() {
            return graph.successorsOf(this);
        }
        // useful shortcut
        public Node connectTo(Node... nodes) {
            for (Node dst : nodes) {
                graph.addEdge(this, dst);
            }
            return this;
        }
    }

    class Edge {
        final graph = DirectedGraph.this;
        final Node src; final Node dst; 
        Edge(Node src, Node dst) {
            graph.assertValidNode(src);
            graph.assertValidNode(dst);
            this.src = src; this.dst = dst;
        }
        public String toString() { return src.toString() + " -> " + dst.toString(); } 
    }

}

DirectedGraph g = new DirectedGraph();
DirectedGraph.Node one = g.addNode(1);
DirectedGraph.Node two = g.addNode(2);
DirectedGraph.Node three = g.addNode(3);
DirectedGraph.Node four = g.addNode(4);

one.connectTo(two, three)
two.connectTo(four);

System.out.println(g.edges);
System.out.println(one.successors());
System.out.println(two.successors());
```

This strategy of representing the domain model in a "1 to 1" mapping, always helped me to "discover" the object model. Then you can improve the implementation for your specific needs (i.e. the running time of `successorsOf` can be improved by using an adjacency list).

Note that in this representation a `Node` and an `Edge` can only exist as a part of a graph. This restriction is not deduced directly from the math representation... but helps to maintain the constraints of a proper graph.

> **Note** You can extract the inner-classes by constructing the `Node` and `Edge` with a parent graph reference.

Comment: Honestly, edges need only be known by their source node. Should only. Otherwise it's a bitch to find all the edges for a given node. It's probably fine to just use singly linked lists for edges, as I implemented in [this example](http://pastebin.com/dH2uUD5D) (unless you need TONS of edges per node, in which case yes use a hash set). Nodes, on the other hand, are going to need to be in a hash **map**, not a hash *set*, because you want to actually *go get* a node, not just know if you already have it. Of course you already have it, you made it earlier... you just don't know where it is.

Comment: Depends on the problem that you try to resolve, for some problems a matrix could be better. But yes usually an Adjacency list (map node->successors) is enough. I did an implementation that matches the math definition first (a set of edges), to show that by having a Graph object is easy to change it later without affecting the interface. Also in most cases you don't need a Node class, an Object is enough.

Comment: My main concern with your implementation is twofold. First, the way he is building it (from a file with list of edges on externally-named nodes) he **must** be able to access a node with a given name quickly. Hence, the nodes should be in a `Map`. Second, if he wishes to traverse the graph he's going to be calling `successorsOf()` *a lot*, and the implementation you have of that (while it does work) **iterates over every single edge in the graph**, which can rapidly become untenable. I'm all for having a `Set` of all edges, but the nodes themselves should also track their own successors.

Comment: ...and if necessary, keep a separate set of their predecessors. You know, whatever you actually need to use. Pretty much anything that takes you from O(N) to O(1) is worth the memory cost.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean with an adjacency list ;) You can make `successorsOf` O(1) by using a `Map<Node, List<Node> >` instead of `Set<Edge>`; the main point that I wanted to highlight is that by mixin the Node representation with the underlying structure is hard to  do that change. But you can make a Graph interface that doesn't expose the implementation, and change it to use more memory and have a better running time, without changing Node or the Graph "clients"

Comment: Yeah, I'm more in the habit of hiding functionality from absolutely everything that doesn't need to see it, but from a structural analysis perspective that would work better.